# String split with delimiter in C#/ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, split, delimiter

If I do this:

```
 string text = "Hello, how are you?";

 string[] split = text.Split('h', 'o');
```

How do I get a list of what delimiter was used between each split?  I'm trying to recreate the string as a whole.

Comment: It's impossible to get the delimiter(s) from the split string array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Davy8 mentioned, there is no built in way. Here's a VERY simple example to get you going on writing a custom method.

```
void Main()
{
    string text = "Hello, how are you?";
    List<SplitDefinition> splitDefinitionList = CustomSplit(text, new char[] { 'h', 'o' });
}

public List<SplitDefinition> CustomSplit(string source, char[] delimiters)
{
    List<SplitDefinition> splitDefinitionList = new List<SplitDefinition>();

    foreach(char d in delimiters)
    {
        SplitDefinition sd = new SplitDefinition(d, source.Split(d));           
        splitDefinitionList.Add(sd);
    }

    return splitDefinitionList;
}

public class SplitDefinition
{
    public SplitDefinition(char delimiter, string[] splits)
    {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
        this.splits = splits;
    }

    public char delimiter { get; set; }
    public string[] splits { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built in way that I'm aware of.  You're probably better off writing your own custom split method that keeps track of the delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible.  The string has been split, so how can you possibly know if the split was based on a 'h' or an 'o'?

Anyways if you can do this:

```
 string[] split = text.Split('h', 'o');
```

then why not also store those characters?